# How can I access related documents within the map function in CouchDb?

Tags: couchdb

Is it possible to get load values from related documents and emit them as part of the key/value along with values from the current document in CouchDb?

Example:

```
{Id: 1, Type: Entity, Name: US, Code: 001}
{Id: 2, Type: Entity, Name: Alaska, Code: AL, Parent_Id: 1}
{Id: 3, Type: Entity, Name: California, Code: CAL, Parent_Id: 1}
{Id: 4, Type: Entity, Name: Juneau, Code: C-JUN, Parent_Id: 2}
```

I would want to read the code, name, etc. from the parent entity and the current entity both and emit them as the key/value in the map function. If the parent has a further parent, I would like to read values from that too. (Link walking in other databases)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In map-reduce, if you `emit()` an object with an `_id` in it, then that id will be the document you get when you query with `?include_docs=true`.

Thus, when map runs on California, it would do `emit(key, {_id: doc.Parent_id, entity: doc})`

If you query the view with `?include_docs=true`, every row will have a `value.entity` for the document about California, but also a `doc` value with the document of the US.

Two restrictions:

1. You can only query 1 level deep per query in this way.
2. TO use the `include_docs` trick, you must know the _id of the linked document when you `emit()`

Another option for this is [view collation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation), where all related or similar documents are emitted so that they are all ajacent in the view. (Usually you emit a key of the id of one document and the Parent_Id of all its children, so they all fall under the same key in the view.

Comment: We are storing hierarchical data. I am aware that I could store the entire path and then emit it in the key. But we also have hierarchies like Org Charts which often change. Updating the path in all related documents may be an issue. Would you suggest using a graph db instead in this case?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention a graph DB as one possibility. CouchDB is awesome, but it is fundamentally not a graph database. If you have very graphy data, perhaps it's worth checking out.